# How to convert bam file to egg file?

Tags: python, 3d-modelling, panda3d

i tried to use a 3D model on panda3d by this code:

```
model = loader.loadModel("modelPath.bam");
model.reparentTo(render);
```

but the model just didn't appear, think it didn't work because it was bam file.

I've been using python for a long time but i'm still new at panda3d.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  Is this the entire program?  Do any errors appear?

Comment: Open cmd, go in the directory where ur .bam file is located and type the following: bam2egg filename.bam filename.egg

Comment: You dont have to type the .bam extension, just modelPath